# (OPENCV) How to access the video capture device in c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a video capture card which has 3 inputs (S-video,Composite,TV). How can I change the input of the capture card in run-time by using OpenCV? I am using Visual Studio 2010 c++ and OpenCV 2.1.

When I try to capture video with "capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0)", It selects the default input of the capture card. Changing the the index of "cvCaptureFromCAM" (capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1)) does not solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance...

Comment: opencv doesnt allow to set the crossbar parameters of video grabbers. If you are developing for windows you can use VideoInput library instead https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput

Comment: I will try that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Micka thank you very much. You helped me a lot.I can change the input of the capture card by using VıdeoInput library. One last problem is setting the freq. of the TV tuner. I can select the tv tuner but couldn't find a way to change the freq. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: sorry, I have no experiences with tv tuners. I would suggest you to use the DirectShow test software "GraphStudioNext". There you can typically change all parameters with a GUI. Once you find the tv tuner settings, you maybe get some information about terms you have to search in VideoInput Library. For example whether the tuner frequencey is part of the crossbar or of the grabber, and so on.

Comment: I was able to use the videoInput library in Console application and find a way to change the freq of tuner. The problem is I cannot use the library in Windows Form Application. I get linking errors while compiling the code. Do you know if the videoInput library can be used in windows form applications ?